# How do I display custom result names in SQLite (on Jupyter Notebook)?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I am new to sql and was wondering how to use the "AS" statement after selecting a column from the database to rename the returned result. Below is the code. Hope you understand what I mean from the code.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd
conn = sql.connect('Jobs.db')


query = 'SELECT COUNT(distinct Major) AS "Unique Majors",
        COUNT(distinct Major_category) AS "Unique category",
        COUNT(distinct Major_code) AS "Unique Code" 
        FROM recent_grads;'


con.execute(query).fetchall()

OUT: [(173, 16, 173)]
```

The code returned the correct values but did not assign the specified names to the results. Is this an error with how I used the AS statement or rather something to do with Jupyter Notebook itself.

Please help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just present the data in a nice format, or actually do something with the results once you get them?

Comment: I want to present the data in a format in which the results have the labels in quotation marks. I've seen it work on PyCharm IDE where the result is a table with the specified name as column headings as shown below. But for some reason on Jupyter Notebook it only returns the values.

unique_majors           unique_category             unique_code

 173                                     16                                      173

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if these names are assigned 'under the hood' so to speak and not visible in the output.

Comment: I think it's the sqlite3 API. Check out [row factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#accessing-columns-by-name-instead-of-by-index)